# Adding the percentage symbol before the index in a slider block in a Qualtrics survey?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I want to add the "%" before indexes in a slider question in a Qualtrics survey. By default when I set up a slider question Qualtrics adds "10", "20" and so on in the top of the table, I want to add before every number a percentage symbol. I guess I have to use the javascript editor, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this javascript to your question:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var qid = this.questionId;
    var ticks = $(qid).select('span.TickContainer');
    for(var i=0; i<ticks.length; i++) {
        var labels = ticks[i].select('span');
        for(var j=0; j<labels.length; j++) {
            var label = labels[j].innerHTML.trim();
            labels[j].innerHTML = " %" + label + " ";
        }
    }   
});
```

P.S. Percent signs usually go after the number, not before.  To change to after, change one line:

```
labels[j].innerHTML = " " + label + "% ";
```

Comment: What is the flow logic here?  I believe I understand that ticks is storing each number as an array, so why is it necessary to then iterate with the labels variable?  (I am not a javascript/html coder, so just trying to see why the need for a double loop)

Comment: This kind of old, but I think it is because of a quirk in Qualtrics html where the first tick contained two labels.